# What does P stand for in commands such as redex PSETEX (Redis) - milliseconds but why?

Tags: redis

P is used to represent Milliseconds in Redis.
Commands such as PSETEX are used to set the expiry in milliseconds (P). 
I can't find any reason why P is used - can anyone explain what the root of the letter P being used for milliseconds is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`P` stand for `precision`, since the precision is improved by using milliseconds.

Note that in the context of `PSETEX` it looks a bit strange, but this originated from the alternate millisecond precision commands that we had to introduce:

- `PEXPIRE`
- `PTTL`

However this was not great to remember, so recent Redis versions, including Redis 2.8.x, supports a fair better form, which is an extension of the `SET` command. So you can write:

```
SET foo bar EX 10 (expire set to 10 seconds)
SET foo bar PX 200 (expire set to 200 milliseconds)
SET foo bar NX (if not exists)
```

Different options can be combined together:

```
SET foo bar PX 200 XX
```

That means: set foo to bar only if the key already exists, with 200 milliseconds TTL.

More info is available in the [SET command documentation](http://redis.io/commands/set).